# How to give relative path in ngView of angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a problem with relative and absolute path in an angularjs application.

Let's take a domain name like www.example.com, and I have an app in this domain called myApp.

So the link to the app is:

> www.example.com/myApp

Now, if I have to give the path of the view which is placed in the views folder of myApp, what do I have to give?

I tried:

```
templateUrl : 'views/pqr.html'
```

but it's not working. The page navigates to:

> www.example.com/pqr.html

But here, no pqr.html exists. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post a complete example to allow others to help you, preferably including a link to plnkr or similar.

Comment: I have no idea of using plnkr or jsfiddle. but you can check the demo over webesperto.com/trackingsystemapp/

Comment: It's very hard to attempt to understand what's going wrong with your app without being able to play with the code; suggest that you take a look at plnkr and put your code in to that so that others can help.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular, the templateURL is where the template is loaded from, it is quite different from the address to which the browser navigates.

Assuming /pqr is the default route for your application you would configure the route provider something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/pqr', {
        templateUrl: 'views/pqr.html',
        controller: 'pqrController',
...
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/pqr'})
```

This will  load the view into the ng-view of index.html (or whatever default page your server has configured)

Comment: Its now working.Actually when i click the link <a href="/pqr">HomeScreen</a> , the url of the browser changes to the domain address.If my domain is www.example.com and my working directory is app, so it will move to domain not in app